# Bootstrap progress bar issue in react component

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

Except Bootstrap Progress Bar All Bootstrap components working in React Component

```
    class Demo extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
              <div>
                <div className="profile_record">
                  <h5 className="progress-label"><strong>PROFILE COMPLETENESS</strong></h5>
                  <div className="progress">
                    <div className="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style={{width: "25%"}} aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">25%</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            )
           }
         }
```

Comment: whats not working?

Comment: Progress bar not visible only 25% text visible on screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it looks like its working as expected, you set tit to:
`aria-valuenow="25"`

Are you sure you included the proper bootstrap `css` and 'js' files?

```js
class Demo extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
              <div>
                <div className="profile_record">
                  <h5 className="progress-label"><strong>PROFILE COMPLETENESS</strong></h5>
                  <div className="progress">
                    <div className="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style={{width: "25%"}} aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">25%</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            )
           }
         }
         
ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Starting from Sep, 2018, you can use the Bootstrap ProgressBar, credits goes here [BootStrap ProgressBar](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/progress/#progress-basic)

```
import { ProgressBar } from "react-bootstrap";

<div>
  <ProgressBar variant="success" now={40} />
  <ProgressBar variant="info" now={20} />
  <ProgressBar variant="warning" now={60} />
  <ProgressBar variant="danger" now={80} />
</div>
```

[image]